# Prove $\lim_{(h,k)\to 0} \dfrac{|f(h,k)|}{|(h,k)|}=0$ for bilinear $f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I have posted the problem **2.12** from Spivaks calculus on Manifolds below along with a solution for it.  Before looking at this solution, I attempted to prove it by writing this

$\lim_{(h,k)\to 0} \dfrac{|f(h,k)|}{|(h,k)|} \leq \lim_{(h,k)\to 0} \dfrac{M|(h,k)|^2}{|(h,k)|}$
for some $M>0$

because earlier there was a question asking

---

[image]

---

And to continue the proof we can now write

$\lim_{(h,k)\to 0} M|(h,k)| = 0$

Does this proof work?

And here is he problem along with the solution

Thanks

[image]

**Solution**

[image]

Comment: The inequality that you wrote is true, but it doesn't follow from applying 1-10, at least not a direct application. From that problem you could get something like $|f(h,k)|\leq M(k)|h|$, by using that $f$ is linear in $h$.

Comment: You can obtain the inequality from $|f(h,k)|=|hf(1,k)|=|hkf(1,1)|\leq \frac{|f(1,1)|}{2}(h^2+k^2)=M|(h,k)|^2$, for $M=\frac{|f(1,1)|}{2}$.

Comment: Awesome.  You could write that as an answer and I will accept it